# BigQuery insert values AS, assume nulls for missing columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Imagine there is a table with 1000 columns.
I want to add a row with values for 20 columns and assume `NULL`s for the rest.

`INSERT VALUES` syntax can be used for that:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl` (
  date, 
  p, 
  ... # 18 more names
)
VALUES(
  DATE('2020-02-01'), 
  'p3',
  ... # 18 more values
)
```

The problem with it is that it is hard to tell which value corresponds to which column. And if you need to change/comment out some value then you have to make edits in two places.

`INSERT SELECT` syntax also can be used:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl`
SELECT 
  DATE('2020-02-01') AS date, 
  'p3' AS p,
  ... # 18 more value AS column
  ... # 980 more NULL AS column
```

Then if I need to comment out some column just one line has to be commented out.
But obviously having to set 980 `NULL`s is an inconvenience.

What is the way to combine both approaches? To achieve something like:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl`
SELECT 
  DATE('2020-02-01') AS date, 
  'p3' AS p,
  ... # 18 more value AS column
```

The query above doesn't work, the error is `Inserted row has wrong column count; Has 20, expected 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first version is really the only one you should ever be using for SQL inserts.  It ensures that every target column is explicitly mentioned, and is unambiguous with regard to where the literals in the `VALUES` clause should go.  You *can* use the version which does not explicitly mention column names.  At first, it might seem that you are saving yourself some code.  But realize that there is a column list which will be used, and it is the list of all the table's columns, in whatever their positions from definition are.  Your code might work, but appreciate that any addition/removal of a column, or changing of column order, can totally break your insert script.  For this reason, most will strongly advocate for the first version.

Comment: I agree with what you say but the question is not about "the version which does not explicitly mention column". I was not intending to use it and never mentioned it. It doesn't solve anything in this case since I want to fill in 20 specific (by name) columns of 1000.
My question is about a more convenient way to make a query that is easy to read and edit.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to achieve your third syntax in SQL.  Just use the first version for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solution, it is combination of above 2 process which you have highlighted in case study:-

```sql
INSERT INTO `tbl` (date, p, 18 other coll names)
SELECT 
  DATE('2020-02-01') AS date, 
  'p3' AS p,
  ... # 18 more value AS column
```

Couple of things you should consider here are :-

1. Other 980 Columns should ne Nullable, that means it should hold NULL values.
2. All 18 columns in Insert line and Select should be in same order so that data will be inserted in same correct order.
3. To Avoid any confusion, try to use Alease in Select Query same as Insert Table Column name. It will remove any ambiguity.

Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: It solves the "tell which value corresponds to which column" problem (which can also be solved by adding comments), but it doesn't solve "have to make edits in two places".

Comment: What do you mean by "make edits in two places", can you give me an example for same what you are expecting.

Comment: If I want to fill in a new 21st column I'll have to add its name into the list of columns(1) and its value into `VALUES`/`SELECT`(2).

Comment: @grabantot . . . You should *always* list the columns for in `insert`, so "making edits in two places" is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @grabantot, if you don't want to edit 2 places then you need to include all insert table's columns names in Select command. Example : If you have 2 Column in Insert table then following 2 command will work  ```insert  into tab1 select Col1, NULL as Col2 from tab2``` and ```insert  into tab1 (Col1, Col2) select Col1, NULL as Col2 from tab2 ```

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, the best way to do what you're describing is to first load to a staging table. I'll assume you can get the values you want to insert into JSON format with keys that correspond to the target column names.

`values.json`

```
{"date": "2020-01-01", "p": "p3", "column": "value", ... }
```

Then generate a schema file for the target table and save it locally

```
bq show --schema project:dataset.tbl > schema.json
```

Load the new data to the staging table using the target schema. This gives you "named" null values for each column present in the target schema but missing from your json, bypassing the need to write them out.

```
bq load --replace --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMIITED_JSON \
project:dataset.stg_tbl values.json schema.json
```

Now the insert select statement works every time

```
insert into `project:dataset.tbl`
select * from `project:dataset.stg_tbl`
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a pure SQL solution but I managed this by loading my staging table with data then running something like:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

table1 = client.get_table(f"{project_id}.{dataset_name}.table1")
table1_col_map = {field.name: field for field in table1.schema}

table2 = client.get_table(f"{project_id}.{dataset_name}.table2")
table2_col_map = {field.name: field for field in table2.schema}

combined_schema = {**table2_col_map, **table1_col_map}

table1.schema = list(combined_schema.values())

client.update_table(table1_cols, ["schema"])
```

Explanation:

This will retrieve the schemas of both, convert their schemas into a dictionary with key as column name and value as the actual field info from the sdk. Then both are combined with dictionary unpacking (the order of unpacking determines which table's columns have precedence when a column is common between them. Finally the combined schema is assigned back to table 1 and used to update the table, adding the missing columns with nulls.